# How do I set global timeout for GET requests on angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

My app uses angular2 http and now I have to put a timeout for all requests. For a single request I'm doing this:

```
this.http.get(this.endPoint)
  .timeout(10000, new Error('timeout'))
  .map( res => res.json());
```

How do I abstract this for all gets that my application have?

Comment: See http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating extending the Http class. I'm not sure if HttpService is the best name, but it worked for me.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response} from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http{
    constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, options);
    }

    request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.request(url, options).timeout(5000, new Error('timeout'));
    }
}
```

I also have to declare the HttpService as a provider and create a factory for that on app.module.ts

```
providers: [
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  {provide: HttpService,useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
      return new HttpService(backend, options);
      }, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions] },
  {provide: AuthHttp, useFactory: getAuthHttp, deps: [HttpService]},
]
```